# an arrow → character getting appeded to files in a .bat script

Tags: batch-file

The following script gets all files with .new_tmp extension and copies them to  a file with the same name but without the .new_tmp extension.  In addition a comment is placed at the top of the file and the .new_tmp file is deleted.

```
echo ^<?php /* > start.tmp
echo */ ?^> > end.tmp
for /R "./mydir" %%I in (*.new_tmp) do (
    copy start.tmp+license.txt+end.tmp+%%I worker.tmp
    move worker.tmp %%~pI%%~nI
    del %%I
)
```

The problem is that a right facing arrow → gets appended to the bottom of all the files

Why is this character getting appended to the end of all the files?

UPDATE
I tried this with a much simpler example and got the same results

```
copy NUL worker.tmp
copy worker.tmp + license.txt + license.txt + license.txt
```

Same problem, an arrow at the end...

I am running under Windows 7

Comment: Which arrow character, ► or → or something else?

Comment: It's probably your edit showing an EOF marker. do you see it if you just do 'more filename" on the commandline?

Comment: Does it work if you _type_ it from keyboard (not copying it) ?

Comment: @Martin yes I see it in notepad or using the more command

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The arrow is a CTRL-Z ascii char that is appended by the `COPY` command when used to concatenate files with the `+` option.

To prevent `COPY` to append the CTRL-Z character, use `COPY /B` for a binary copy.

So, your command would be

```
COPY /B start.tmp+license.txt+end.tmp+%%I worker.tmp
```

Comment: thanks! Was searching all around why in my SSIS Package, there was that strange Arrow character  (EOF).  I found that it was due to the copy FileA+FileB FileA (to concatenate).   An important note : i had the copy /b argument  [in lowercase] and it will not work.  You have to put it UPPER CASE (copy /B)

Comment: Oddly it still leaves in the  ASCII 1AH char in between, contrary to that, appending the `/B` to the end of the statement works.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this @PA.!

Answer (score 3):

When /b follows Destination, copy does not add an end-of-file character.

This is how I would solve the problem:

```
COPY start.tmp+license.txt+end.tmp+%%I worker.tmp /B
```