# create a header for flat file destination using ssis

Tags: ssis

I have a ssis package scheduled hourly and that package produces a flat file (text file) each time.

Is there a way to generate a header for each of those flat file generated?

I am thinking to use 'UNION' to merge two flat files (header & body), however I cannot control which file would go first.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *might* be simpler, depending on your preference:

1. Create a text file with your header
2. In an execute process task run this: `COPY HeaderFile.TXT + InputFile.TXT OUTPUT.TXT` to stick the files together

If you get an arrow character at the end of the file use this instead:

`COPY /B HeaderFile.TXT + InputFile.TXT OUTPUT.TXT`

(see [an arrow → character getting appeded to files in a .bat script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313960/an-arrow-%E2%86%92-character-getting-appeded-to-files-in-a-bat-script))

Comment: i tried this method, but it seems to include a arrow symbol at the end of output?

Comment: That's curious... and the arrow symbol is not present in the original file? What character is it if you check the Ascii codes in a text editor? Which text editor are you using to view?

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313960/an-arrow-%E2%86%92-character-getting-appeded-to-files-in-a-bat-script you need to use `/B` to the copy command. I will edit the answe accordingly

Comment: The only shame is that this method cannot dynamically generate output file name? I need to specify the name in bat file?

Comment: You can populate the contents of the Execute Process Task with an expression. That will let you do that. At some point it might be better to use a script but I reckon so far so good.

Answer (score 6):

Click on the connection in Connection Manager and set the "ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow" = True .

Answer (score 3):

In my SSIS there is actually a property under Custom Properties named Header. Worked great for me.
* just discovered that you can also use an expression with the property [Flat File Destination].[Header] and set it to a variable on the Data Flow task.

Comment: FYI: This option only appears in the list of options when viewing the expressions specifically for a Data Flow task. This will not be visible if you right click the flat file destination object and view the properties/expressions, but only if you right click and open properties of the task itself. This caught me up for a while earlier when attempting to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

I accomplished this by creating two separate data flow tasks.  The first takes and totals data and adds in addition fields to make the first header record.  The second task adds in the rows we their independent metadata.  Trick is in the first flat file destination have it overwrite the previous file and in the second destination use the same file but uncheck the overwrite data.  If the file name is dynamic you can set the file name as a global variable and initialize it on start and the time-stamped file name and then use the variable as the destination file name instead.

Comment: Excellent, a very easy solution @Chris, and you could add a footer data flow task...

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Using a script component is the easiest way I found to do it. I had played around with writing the data I wanted to a text file using a flat file destination, then using a script task to append a header and footer. You could do that if you like.

I found it was simpler to just do it in one step, i.e. route your data flow into a script task which writes the header in PreExecute, and all the data rows in ProcessInputRow, and optionally a footer in PostExecute.

Something like this;

```
TextWriter tw;

public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();
    tw = new StreamWriter(Variables.requestFname);
    tw.WriteLine("HEADER");
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    tw.WriteLine(Row.WhateverFieldsYouNeed);
}

public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    tw.WriteLine("FOOTER");
    tw.Close();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the header dynamically changes every time

Comment: Of course. "HEADER" is just a placeholder for whatever dynamic header you need. For example, like i've used Variables.requestFname to determine where the file will be written, you can create another string variable in SSIS to represent the header. You could have this evaluate to an expression at runtime, and replace "HEADER" in my code with Variables.HeaderVariable. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, I will try this later. However, the 'header' has more than 255 char and I am not sure if it can be wrapped in a variable?

Comment: There is an `Object` type variable in SSIS that you could use to handle dynamic situations such as selecting from a table and dumping the data into a variable of type `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Properties of data flow.

Go to control flow page
Select properties pan of Data Flow component
Go to Expressions and select [Flat File Destination].[Header]
Here you can Set the value for this property dynamically or not