# How to represent a right arrow symbol existing in a CSV file within a Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that replaces text in a csv - the code was copied from here ([Replace specific text in csv via commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605232/replace-specific-text-in-csv-via-commandline)...however) I need to alter it so that it replaces a right arrow symbol in my input file.  The code does not work as it is shown below so I must be representing that symbol / character incorrectly in some way.

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion

set filename=CARDSHIPPROP.csv
set originalText1=
set "replacedText1=XKXD"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %filename%') do (
    set "line=%%a"
if defined line (
    call set "line=%%line:%originalText1%=%replacedText1%%%"
    echo !line!>> CARDSHIPPROP_New.csv
) else (
    echo.
)
```

)

Comment: What character do you mean? the one with ASCII `0x1A`?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would determine the ASCII identifying value just offhand - if it helps I believe that particular character is being added upstream in a separate process similiar to what is described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313960/an-arrow-%E2%86%92-character-getting-appeded-to-files-in-a-bat-script

Comment: Open your CSV file with a hex. editor and you'll see the codes... Or just use `type` -- if the arrow and everything behind is truncated, it's the EOF (end-of-file) character (code 0x1A)...

Comment: To get that character into a variable (say `EOF`), do this: `copy /Y nul eof.tmp /A & (for /F %C in (eof.tmp) do set "EOF=%C") & del eof.tmp` (double up the `%`-signs in a batch file)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to edit/replace files with *special characters*, This might help you.

The problem with your original script aside, I have not only created a solution that works, but I have redesigned it with better execution added features. The current script you're using does not preserve empty lines.

```
@echo off
@setLocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "InputFile=file.csv"
set "OriginalText=Hello There"
set "ReplacedText=Hello > There"

REM | Make sure we only edit the proper line.
FOR /F "delims=" %%n IN ('findstr /n "^" %InputFile%') DO (
    SET "line=%%n"
    SET "Modified=!line:%OriginalText%=%ReplacedText%!"
    SET "Modified=!Modified:*:=!"

    REM | Output the entire edited CSV to a temporary file.
    >> %InputFile%.TEMP ECHO(!Modified!
)

Rem | Delete Original File, Restore New
DEL %InputFile%
REN %InputFile%.TEMP %InputFile%

goto :EOF
```

Bellow I will attempt to explain what each `SET` command is doing.

- `SET "line=%%n"` - Set the current `%%A` to string. (This will be the line)
- `SET "Modified=!line:%OriginalText%=%ReplacedText%!"` - Replace string containing `%OriginalText%` to respected `%ReplaceText%` result.
- `SET "Modified=!Modified:*:=!"` - Remove the `1:`, `2:`, `3:`, exc created by `findstr /n`

The `>> %InputFile%.TEMP ECHO(!Modified!` will output that preticular line into the new text file.

I personally would suggest that if you use the `set "String="` with quotes, every other `set` command uses them also. There are some exceptions but in this case, use them!

---

**EDIT:**

Since it appears the OP is asking for special character support `from` & `to` text, This will be the updated method.

First of all this can be done on an 15 character `powershell` command. If you don't need a pure batch method and are willing to make it a hybrid, I suggest doing that. However, for a pure batch solution, continue reading.

Batch has a hard time processing special characters into functions without something breaking. However, It can still be done and I will get you on the right path.

Bellow there are two scripts, `ReplaceScript.bat` and `MainCode.Bat`.
The

- The `MainCode.Bat` is *your* main batch script. Can be any name.
- The `ReplaceScript.bat` is a script we will be `call`'ing to from `MainCode.Bat. This replace script file can be pasted at the bottom of`MainCode.Bat` if desired but due to size I like to leave it out.

To use the `ReplaceScript.bat` - It goes as following:

> ```
> Rem | Usage: call "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
> Rem | call - Calls external script
> Rem | "1" - Name of External script
> Rem | "2" - File to Edit
> Rem | "3" - Text to replace ex: red apple
> Rem | "4" - Text to replace to ex: green apple
> Rem | "5" - Output file
> ```
>
> `call "%ReplaceScript%" "%InputTEXT%" "%SEARCHTEXT%" "%REPLACETEXT%"  "%OutputTEXT%"`

**MainCode.bat:**

```
@ECHO OFF

set "InputFile=file.csv"
set "OriginalText=Hello There"
set "ReplacedText=Hello > There"

Rem | Call Replace Script
call "ReplaceScript.bat" "%CustomINI%" "%OriginalText%" "%ReplacedText%"  "%InputFile%.TEMP"

Rem | Delete Original File, Restore New
DEL %InputFile%
REN %InputFile%.TEMP %InputFile%

goto :EOF
```

**ReplaceScript.bat:** (NOT MADE BY ME; Respected owner unknown - If its yours contact me)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "FILE_I=%~1"
set "SEARCH=%~2"
set "REPLAC=%~3"
set "FILE_O=%~4"
set "FLAG=%~5"
if not defined FILE_I exit /B 1
if not defined SEARCH exit /B 1
if not defined FILE_O set "FILE_O=con"
if defined FLAG set "FLAG=#"

for /F "delims=" %%L in ('
    findstr /N /R "^" "%FILE_I%" ^& break ^> "%FILE_O%"
') do (
    set "STRING=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "STRING=!STRING:*:=!"
    call :REPL RETURN STRING SEARCH REPLAC %FLAG%
    >> "%FILE_O%" echo(!RETURN!
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B


:REPL  rtn_string  ref_string  ref_search  ref_replac  flag
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "STR=!%~2!"
set "SCH=!%~3!"
set "RPL=!%~4!"
if not defined SCH endlocal & set "%~1=" & exit /B 1
set "SCH_CHR=!SCH:~,1!"
if not "%~5"=="" set "SCH_CHR="
if "!SCH_CHR!"=="=" set "SCH_CHR=" & rem = terminates search string
if "!SCH_CHR!"==""^" set "SCH_CHR=" & rem " could derange syntax
if "!SCH_CHR!"=="%%" set "SCH_CHR=" & rem % ends variable expansion
if "!SCH_CHR!"=="^!" set "SCH_CHR=" & rem ! ends variable expansion
call :LEN SCH_LEN SCH
call :LEN RPL_LEN RPL
set /A RED_LEN=SCH_LEN-1
set "RES="
:LOOP
call :LEN STR_LEN STR
if not defined STR goto :END
if defined SCH_CHR (
    set "WRK=!STR:*%SCH_CHR%=!"
    if "!WRK!"=="!STR!" (
        set "RES=!RES!!STR!"
        set "STR="
    ) else (
        call :LEN WRK_LEN WRK
        set /A DFF_LEN=STR_LEN-WRK_LEN-1,INC_LEN=DFF_LEN+1,MOR_LEN=DFF_LEN+SCH_LEN
        for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%M in ("!DFF_LEN!,!INC_LEN!,!MOR_LEN!") do (
            rem set "RES=!RES!!STR:~,%%M!"
            if defined WRK set "WRK=!WRK:~,%RED_LEN%!"
            if "!STR:~%%M,1!!WRK!"=="!SCH!" (
                set "RES=!RES!!STR:~,%%M!!RPL!"
                set "STR=!STR:~%%O!"
            ) else (
                set "RES=!RES!!STR:~,%%N!"
                set "STR=!STR:~%%N!"
            )
        )
    )
) else (
    if "!STR:~,%SCH_LEN%!"=="!SCH!" (
        set "RES=!RES!!RPL!"
        set "STR=!STR:~%SCH_LEN%!"
    ) else (
        set "RES=!RES!!STR:~,1!"
        set "STR=!STR:~1!"
    )
)
goto :LOOP
:END
if defined RES (
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%S in ("!RES!") do (
        endlocal
        set "%~1=%%S"
    )
) else endlocal & set "%~1="
exit /B


:LEN  rtn_length  ref_string
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "STR=!%~2!"
if not defined STR (set /A LEN=0) else (set /A LEN=1)
for %%L in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if defined STR (
        set "INT=!STR:~%%L!"
        if not "!INT!"=="" set /A LEN+=%%L & set "STR=!INT!"
    )
)
endlocal & set "%~1=%LEN%"
exit /B
```

---

I personally would suggest that if you use the `set "String="` with quotes, every other `set` command uses them also. There are some exceptions but in this case, use them!

For further help or understanding on any of the commands do the following:

- `call /?`
- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `goto /?`
- So on.

Comment: Sorry but where in your solution above have you indicated the symbol that I'm referring to (and I apologize if I am just missing it).  I see you have the line:  set "OriginalText=Hello There"  but  I don't see any reference to a special character (specifically that right arrow I mentioned before) unless I am just missing it.

Comment: I see that my right arrow special character wasn't pasted in when I wrote my original post - sorry for the confusion.  Still not clear in the solution provided how to represent a special character since the original text variable is represented by a text string in your example above.  I am assuming there is a specific trick to representing special characters in a batch file but please correct me if I am wrong on that.  Everything I have tried to this point has failed.

Comment: @TraceDot79 The original scrip I posted was for replacing `to` a special character, not from it. To do this you will need a more complex script to determine if the string has one. I will update my response.